# A little question about the proof of *compactness* implying *limit point compactness* .

Tags: general-topology, compactness

$X$  is  an  arbitrary topological  space  which  is  *compact* .  We  have to prove that $X$ is limit point compact .

So , $A$ be any *infinite* set if $X$ . If  we  suppose  $A$  *"has  no  limit  points"*  then  only  the  points  inside $A$ can  be  considered  as  limits  of  $A$. Thus  $A$  becomes  a  closed  set . Now   for  each $a\in A$ ,  we  choose  a  nbd  $U_a$ of $a$ such  that $U_a$ intersect  $A%$   at  only  one  point  $a$ .

Now  here  is  the  problem  **:** How  do  I  make  sure  that  such  a  nbd  $U_a$ exist $?$ 
 Thnks.

Comment: Otherwise, $a$ would be a limit point of $A$.

Comment: Oh ,  got  it .  Stupid  question  anyway .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$  has  *"no  limit  points"*  implying  all  points  of  $A$  are  *isolated points*. That  is  taken  any  point  of  $A$ ,  $a$ a nbd  like  $U_a$  must  exist for   otherwise that  point  $a$  will  become  a  *"limit  point"*  of  $A$ .